# Missing fingerprint cookie in the request headers in loadrurnner replay

Tags: loadrunner

We added headers as like blow in loadrunner script

web_add_header("Authorization", "Bearer eydfbdgbdgggggggggggggggggggge445tggbgbgfbfbbdfbdfbfcbfdbfddfvdffdgd
"0;
we_add_cookie("__Secure-Fgp=233225223rgfsssgsgsdg33434sfsfvfsv322=; Path=/; Secure; domain=domain.com");

Web_custom_request("request");

Getting below error when we replay the script in loadrunner

"error":"400","Message":"**Missing fingerprint cookie in the request headers**"

**Error: -26631:HTTP Status-Code=400(Bad Request)**

Please help me to overcome the issues

Comment: Please share the following (a) your level of training with LoadRunner (b) what you have tried (c) the results of [b] versus your expected results.